# How to extract text from rotated PDF without saving it from web response object using PyPDF2 or any other package?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, pypdf, pdftotext, pdf-scraping

I want to extract text from [this link](https://www.mbmc.gov.in/master_c/download_file/63161). Here the pdf is rotated and I'm getting a blank response or empty string when i try to rotate it and extract and even if i simply try to extract text then also I'm getting blank response/ empty string. Please suggest what could be done so that i can extract the text without saving the file on my system.

```
import requests
import PyPDF2
from io import BytesIO

pdf_resp = requests.Session().get("https://www.mbmc.gov.in/master_c/download_file/63161")
pdf_file_obj = BytesIO(pdf_resp.content)
pdf_table_text = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file_obj).getPage(0).rotateClockwise(90).extractText()
```

Comment: You need to OCR it, I don't think PyPDF does that. I would try ABBYY + save as csv for this one.

Comment: @pguardiario is there a way through which we can do it without saving the file ?

Comment: There might be an api for that, I'm not sure.

Comment: I got the answer, actually the pdf i was trying to parse was made of images and not text and that's why i was not able to do it.. I used camelot to do the job for me

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I wasn't clear about what OCR means